# Java Swing paintImmediately() method works on main thread instead of EDT thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, animation, edt

I am writing a program, which is supposed to update and render animation for each frame. I have an `AnimationPanel` class which extends `JPanel` and an `Animation` class, which maintains my animation with an infinity loop. I was invoking `paintComponent` method by JPanel's `paintImmediately` method from `animation` (`Animation` object) and everything was working fast and well, until I added a new component to the JFrame. Then, components started to overlap one another, because new components were working on the EDT thread, but my `animation` was working on the main thread and somehow it was calling `paintImmediately` and then `paintComponent` also in the main thread, but of course it shouldn't. I tried to put the `paintImmediately` part of code to EDT thread and it worked, but the performance was really poor (instead of >100fps only ~40fps) and animation started lagging and it was behaving the same way as if it was `repaint()` method instead. So I guess I did something wrong, but I totally don't know what.
The `paintComponent` method looks like this:

```java
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    animation.render(g2d);
}
```

and `render` method look like this:

```java
public void render(Graphics2D g2d) {
    objects.forEach((o) -> o.render(g2d));
}
```

Each object has its own `render` method, which usually is `g2d.fill(/*object's shape*/)`

The `render()` method called by loop:

```java
private void render() {
    //It calls paintComponent in the main thread
    panel.paintImmediately(0, 0, panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight());
}
```

and its modification which was laggy:

```java
private void render() {
    //It calls paintComponent int the EDT thread
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(()->panel.paintImmediately(0, 0, panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight()));
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Off topic maybe, but who still uses Swing? and why?

Comment: School project, default java is required :/ Are there any better default java libraries for graphics?

Comment: Absolutely. But I also had to use Swing in School :/ 
Generally: JavaFX is just the new Swing. It's the official Oracle GUI/graphics Library and included in the default installation

Comment: Alright, I'll try it then. Thanks!

Comment: Btw. JavaFX comes with the FXML System  as recommended (but not necessary) entrypoint. Any tutorial that loads a file in the launch (main) method is overcomplicating it for your usecase

Comment: *which maintains my animation with an infinity loop.* - you should not be using a loop. Instead you use a Swing Timer. You should not be invoking paintImmediately() or use invokeAndWait(...). Just use repaint() on the panel. I have never seen JavaFX included in the base JDK up to version 11. Maybe that has changed in version 14.

Comment: But when using repaint() i can see that there are frames which weren't rendered, because repaint() doesn't act at once. That is why I tried using paintimmediately(). However I will try use Timer and repaint(), maybe it will work better, thanks!